# How do I use REVTeX?

Tags: revtex

This seems like a really stupid question, but I am confused. I am LaTeX-ing papers for a professor, but APS requires the REVTeX format. Is it as simple as `\documentclass{revtex4-1}`, and remains as a .tex file?

Are there formatting requirements (for APS/AIP) I should look out for as well? I don't like how the sections are numbered with Roman numerals, but is that one of those things that are required?

Comment: In my answer for your preceeding question, which is for an uknown reason removed, you could see, that the answers for the first paragraph are: yes.

Comment: Ah, sorry I did delete it because I thought it was be dumb to ask a question when I don't even know the REVTeX and APS formatting basics. Thanks!

Comment: Almost every journal has author guidelines, see e.g. here: http://prb.aps.org/author-information/

Comment: The journal-specific formatting requirements for journals which require revtex are generally handled by passing options to revtex -- from one of my papers: `\documentclass[aip,apl,reprint,article,floatfix]{revtex4-1}`.  If you set the correct options, then 99% of the time when you get to something you don't like, you just ignore it and move on.  I can strongly recommend against using revtex for anything except submissions to journals which require it.  Also note that many of these journals (and many more besides) have some rather strict requirements eg. on .bib files.

Answer (score 3):

I highly reccomend you read the REVTeX documentation located [on the REVTeX Home Page](http://publish.aps.org/revtex). The authors guide can be found there, as well as other documents pertaining to your questions.

In short, yes. after RevTex is installed, it really is that simple.
As for formatting requirements, that is going to be dependent on who you're submitting this to, and what they are looking for. If you're unsure, I would advise you to use whatever the big journals like ["Nature"](http://www.nature.com/nature/authors/gta/) are using if you don't have a target audience in mind.

Since you're in university, I suggest you check with your university's guidelines and consult your professor, maybe your university has a specific LaTeX template they would like you to use.

Comment: Mentioning Nature here is pretty weird. They only accept "Manuscript files in PDF, Word, WordPerfect, EPS, PostScript, RTF format". Sounds like stone age.

Comment: Haha, they are. They're so weird that I have to mention them or else he might think something crazy like that physicists can agree on something.